# How to fix "can't connect to Visual Studio Code marketplace"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been dealing with this problem for the last couple of days. It says it **can't connect to marketplace**, even though I have a proper internet connection. Can you help me please,  as I can't download any extensions.

Comment: did you find a solution?